# Ignore exception and continue to insert the rest of the data

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I have the following codes snippet. I remove further details. I have a for loop with all the data in it. The I run the for loop for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++). What happens is that the moment any one of the data cause the sql with error say the data has a slash etc then it cause exception and the rest of the for loop cant continue. How can I like skip the one with the exception and continue with rest?

Here is a the codes.

```
    Connection dbconn = null;
    Statement stmt1 = null;
    Statement stmt2 = null;
    try
    {
        dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1", "tes1", "te15");
        stmt1 = dbconn.createStatement();
        stmt2 = dbconn.createStatement();
        DateFormat outDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        String value = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {

            String insertCommand = "INSERT INTO command SET .........";
            System.out.println("\n SET INSERT :" + insertCommand);
            int count = stmt1.executeUpdate(insertCommand);
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("MyError Error SQL Exception : " + ex.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception rollback)
    {
        System.out.println("\nRollback :");
        rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\n Error here :");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (stmt1 != null)
            {
                stmt1.close();
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("MyError: SQLException has been caught for stmt1 close");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try
        {
            if (stmt2 != null)
            {
                stmt2.close();
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("MyError: SQLException has been caught for stmt2 close");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try
        {
            if (dbconn != null)
            {
                dbconn.close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("MyError: dbConn is null in finally close");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("MyError: SQLException has been caught for dbConn close");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about `INSERT IGNORE ....` as a test. Then it reality fix the real problem? I am not sure *ignore* will actually survive the exception part.

Comment: if you get an exception because your data caused an sql syntax error, then you're probably vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Yes I understand about the vulnerability but I got no choice but to ignore that exception and continue the rest?

Comment: isn't your catch for the rollback in a faulty state of squiggly wraps?

Comment: Which one do you mean ? I dont get your ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the error in the loop too

```
....
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    try {
        String insertCommand = "INSERT INTO command SET .........";
        System.out.println("\n SET INSERT :" + insertCommand);
        int count = stmt1.executeUpdate(insertCommand);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Better catch the real exception
            // Handle the exception 
        }
}
....
```

Comment: yes that is what I am doing I tried this  
If I put just like this try { catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("‌​Ignore Error SQL Exception : "+ex.toString()); ex.printStackTrace(S‌​ystem.out); } i have put the word ignore so at least I know this was ignore will this be sufficient ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the try/catch block inside the for, around `executeUpdate(insertCommand);`

Comment: If I put just like this  try { catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Ignore Error SQL Exception : "+ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
       } i have put the word ignore so at least I know this was ignore will this be sufficient ?